# HighCharts export graph failing

Tags: jquery, highcharts

We use highCharts however all of a sudden this morning exporting to any of the options (JPEG, PDF etc..) fails.  Have tried IE, FF and Chrome, they all fail.  The IE 8 (the SOE) behavior is the little yellow warning strip appears in the top of the browser saying 'Internet Explorer has modified this page to help prevent cross-site scripting.  Click here for more information'  The only character in the browser is a #

is anybody seen/getting this?

Comment: Could you reproduce issue on jsFiddle? Maybe server was down for a while.

Comment: yes you are correct the export.highcharts.com part of the site was down.  Seems to be ok now